# React Native TextInput is made transparent when editable={false} - how to prevent this behaviour?

Tags: react-native, input

By default, it seems like the text in a TextInput is put at half opacity when editable={false}. This appears to combine with any opacity passed in via a style object - if you pass in opacity: 1 the effect still happens, and if you pass in opacity: 0.5 the "disabled" opacity is ~0.25. How can I stop this behaviour? Tested on Android but may also occur on iOS. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try giving a color prop?

Answer (score 4):

I solved this problem doing this:

```
<View pointerEvents='none'>
  <TextInput
    ...
    editable={true}
  />
</View>
```

PointerEvents documentation: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view#pointerevents